# Check for event listener collisions with Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I have this simple code in my Javascript:

```
element.addEventListener('mouseover', my_function, false);
element.addEventListener('mouseout', my_function, false);
```

This matches both `mouseover` AND `mouseout`. The problem is that in same cases the two events are triggered at the same time.

I would like kind of a OR behaviour. If one of the events are triggered, don't trigger the other. Is it possible in some built in way?

The workaround would be to set a global variable which keeps track of if an event just has been triggered.

Comment: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` won't occur simultaneous on same element

Comment: How would you trigger mouseout without a mouseover

Comment: @charlietfl When I move the mouse from one element to another I get 2 counts instead of one. But maybe I need to approach it differently.

Comment: Sure...you leave one...then enter the other.... events on 2 different elements not same. Sounds more like a logic issue than an event one